# How to call multiple application from single application in android

Tags: android-intent

I am new to android.i have created one application.i am trying to call multiple application in single application.
i have created app in that first activity i used gridview.
on the click of each grid view icon i am launching another application with intent.i.e.

```
 Intent intent = new intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.setclassName("pakagename","pakageName.ClassName");
 startActivity(intent);
```

but its failed to launch another application..
is there any need to change in AndroidManifest file?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.maps.mytracks/com.google.android.apps.mytracks.MyTracks"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
startActivity(intent);
```

add one line before startActivity(intent);

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```